# PySpark Logistic regression model weights are inconsistent between runs

Tags: apache-spark, optimization, pyspark, logistic-regression

I am training a pyspark logistic regression model using pyspark mllib. I am noticing that the weights are not being consistent in between runs. I have set the random seed in the training script and also am making a deterministic random split (by setting seed in trainvalidation split) between training and testing data using TrainValidationSplit.

With low number of records i.e., less than 1million input records, the model weights match exactly between runs. But as I increase the volume of the data (to >20M records), I am noticing that the weights are fluctuating. Some of them are zero during one iteration while in other iterations, they have values in the 10^(-3) range. Can anyone help me understand why this could be happening?

Note: I am doing a constrained optimization - I am setting lower bounds weights and intercept to be zero and non-negative.

Here is how I split the data,

```
model = LogisticRegression(
        featuresCol=input_vector,
        labelCol=label,
        tol=args.tolerance,
        maxIter=args.max_iterations
    )

vldtr = TrainValidationSplit(
        estimator=model,
        evaluator=BinaryClassificationEvaluator(),
        estimatorParamMaps=parameter_grid,
        seed=12,
        )
```

With this setup, the weights are staying consistent when the data volume is low (<2M records). But when I try to train the model with more records (>20M records), I am seeing that the weights are becoming inconsistent. Some of them are zero in a certain iteration and the same weights are non-zero in subsequent iteration.

Does anyone have intuition on why this might be happening? Thanks in advance!